# What would cause npm live-server to stop detecting file changes?

Tags: javascript, server, npm-live-server

This was working on my system and now is not.  I have live-server version 0.8.1 installed globally.

```
npm install live-server -g
```

But when I start it I don't get the "Live reload enabled." message in the browser console.

I've uninstalled it completely and re-installed it to no avail.

The http server is working.  It will serve up my index.html and all related content.  It just won't detect file changes.

Starting live-server:

```
live-server --open=src
```

I'm using typescript outputting js to src/dist/...  I've verified that the file is changing.  I can modify the js directly as well.  In no case does live-server detect any changes.

File system permissions?
Cached configuration?

What's causing this?

Comment: Please correctly tag your question, since this is more than js.

Comment: Is there a config for live-server?

Comment: No config for live-server.

Answer (score 3):

I had been having this issue as well, and stumbled across one exchange between Ritwick Dey (author of live-server), and a dev having the same issues.

As it turns out, it's as simple as not using a self-closing  tag.

In my case, I was using React, and the line in question (in my HTML file) was

```
<script src="/scripts/app.js" />
```

Changing it to the following immediately fixed my issue, and got the "Live reload enabled" message in my Console, and hot reloading to work again.

```
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

(here's a link to the conversation: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/82)

Comment: It looks like a wierd suggestion but it worked for me. Don't forget to restart the server again. Thanks, Eric.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been a Chrome caching issue.
I opened Safari and voila, everything started working.  Closed Safari and now Chrome is working again.

I'm going to call this a bizarre environmental fluke.